# Regex to find Two string are same in Input

Tags: php, regex

I have following line

```
.SetTimeouts(Gqeohynrfkjdyhe5gahsChlnwgkue, 26545 ,Gqeohynrfkjdyhe5gahsChlnwgkue,IfjrntgkkjshsMihbqyf)
```

I need a regex to find first and third string are same within parentheses

My regex is

```
.SetTimeouts\([\w]*, [0-9]{5} ,[\w]*,[\w]*\)
```

It will return excat output, but i need to sure both first and third are same

Comment: Show us your code and we can help. Also some details, like you always want to compare the 1st and 3rd element inside the parentheses?  The string is the one inside the parentheses (looks more like an array though).

Comment: @pr1nc3, Please check now

Comment: Which Regex version are you going to use? On which language?

Comment: @flaviodesousa--Its in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if you are using PHP, you're going to use PCRE regexes

Try

```
\.SetTimeouts\((\w*)\s*,\s*[0-9]{5}\s*,\s*\1\s*,\s*\w*\)
```

where `(\w*)` selects the first string and `\1` ensures the 3rd argument matches the first string. Added some `\s*` to support optional spacing.

It could be advisable to change it to

```
\.SetTimeouts\((\w+)\s*,\s*[0-9]{5}\s*,\s*\1\s*,\s*\w+\)
```

in order to avoid empty strings as the 1st and 4th arguments.

Comment: @pavithranG If that answered your question just mark it as answered.